# VisualVM is not displaying any java application except itself

Tags: visualvm

I'm running a jboss application server that hosts my ear file. Java version is 1.6.0.35. If I run Java VisualVM on the machine where my jboss is running I only see 'VisualVM' under the node 'Local' in the left side tree view. I tried making a JMX connection as it said in other threads, but it times out and connection cannot be made.

Note: If I run visualVM on my development machine it is able to see the jboss running. The only difference is that on my dev box I have the code unnong from Eclipse IDE and on my deployment machine there is no IDE and it runs as a process.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that VisualVM runs under the same user as jboss application.